# Dealing with quotes in html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting a data element of an image in my html.erb file:

```
<img src="<%=image%>" data-description="<%= auto_link(step.description)%>"/>
```

The issue is that there there are sometimes quotes in my step.description that interfere so that data-description is not set correctly, such as:

```
<img src="..." data-description="<pre><code class=" language-java"="" style="width: 193px; height: 257px; margin-left: -96.5px; margin-top: -128.5px; opacity: 1;">
```

How can I remove conflicting quotes in my erb file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a helper method called `j` or `escape_javascript` that will escape quotes in a string and make it possible to add a string with quotes to an attribute on an element like you're trying to do. [More info here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript)

So, change your code to:

```
<img src="<%=image%>" data-description="<%=j auto_link(step.description)%>"/>
```

Just adding that `j` will do it for any sort of string with quotes.

If you're also putting HTML inside an HTML attribute you will have to escape html too with the [html_escape](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape) helper:

```
<img src="<%=image%>" data-description="<%=h j(auto_link(step.description))%>"/>
```

`h` is short for `html_escape`. That should escape the tags inside the attribute and not break your layout.

Comment: Thanks for your response - the page doesn't load when I add this.  I think my rails app isn't recognizing it?  I'm using 3.2.15

Comment: try `escape_javascript` rather than `j`. This one was available even in Rails 3.1.1: http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper:escape_javascript

Comment: The other problem might be that you're trying to put html inside an html attribute. Updated my answer to account for this.

Comment: thanks again for your response, but the page still isn't loading after adding this edit.  here is what gets outputted: data-description="<pre><code class=\"language-java\">/** Arduino Processing Example\n *  "/>

Comment: Those HTML tags within your data attribute still aren't being escaped. Sure you're using `h`? 
It should output a string that looks like `&gt;pre&lt;&gt;code class=\"language...`

Comment: yes, this is what I have:  data-description="<%=h j(auto_link(step.description))%>"

Comment: I get the error http://0.0.0.0:3000/projects/42/undefined 404 (Not Found) which points to a closing script tag

Comment: That's an unrelated error. See how's your path contains `undefined` in it? Something else is wrong.

Comment: I decided to get rid of autolink and just used <%= j step.description %>  Thanks for your help!